# Setting text in a TextView at runtime

Tags: android, textview, runtime, settext

I'm a newbie to Android Development so I'm probably drowning in an inch of water...
I have a layout.xml file with a TextView and some buttons, set where i need them.
Is there a way to change just the text displayed without having to recreate the entire layout programmatically?  Thanks for you patience :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After defining your `TextView` in `onCreate()`, just call `setText(string)` property.

***Edited:***

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_current_layout);
TextView mytextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
mytextview.setText("I'm called from your activity");
```

Enjoy :-)

Comment: So if I have in the layout.xml something like this:
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Dummy test" />
I just need to call: textView1.setText("Right text");?

Comment: @PietroNobili It's okay, What's your problem !?

Comment: @PietroNobili you need to use findViewById() to get a reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

inside of your onCreate() **after** you call setContentView() put this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("Some new text");
```

and replace `textView1` with the ID of your TextView from inside of your layout, there should be something like this:

```
<TextView
...
...
android:id="@+id/textView1" />
```

whatever is after the slash in `@+id/` is what you'll need to put after `R.id.`

And if you don't have an `android:id` line then create one.